# Terraform: how do you inspect sensitive data?

Tags: security, terraform

In a resource of type `aws_ecs_task_definition` my plan has an line that looks like this:

```
~ container_definitions    = (sensitive) # forces replacement
```

Now in principle this could be doing anything - deleting all my containers, spinning up bitcoin mining containers, etc.

Is there any way I can look at the data, both the old and the new?

Comment: This is plan's outout. You don't have source code of TF script that you are executing?

Comment: I do but I have a bunch of function calls in the source and I'm hoping to see the final result.

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but may be handy for others:

If you use an aws_ssm_parameter data source in your container definition, the whole definition becomes sensitive. This feature was introduced in terraform 0.14 and there is no "nonsensitive" argument to aws_ssm_parameter, but terraform 0.15 introduces the function: https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/functions/nonsensitive.html